# Table in landscape mode caused page break in two column document

Tags: tables

I inserted a table using `landscape` and `afterpage` packages.

But, in two columns document, the text is cut after inserting the table.

[image]

Here is an example of my code:

```
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}   
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llllllllllllll}
....
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
}
```

Comment: on page 1 of the afterpage documentation it explicitly states that twocolumn documents are not supported.

Comment: I am surprised that you got output at all with `\afterpage` but even just with `landscape` it necessarily starts a new page so will leave the second column blank, you can't have a two column page with the columns in different orientations, one portrait and one landscape.  Perhaps you are looking for  `sidewaystable` from the rotating package.

Comment: unrelated but `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llllllllllllll}` should have an X column (or more likely should be using tabular rather than tabularx as there is no line breaking in the cells)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, so what should I do?

Comment: as I say look at sidewaystable environment or simply use `\rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}.....\end{tabular}}`  If you provided a small complete example that showed the problem, someone will probably post a tested solution.

Comment: You could use \afterpage\afterpage{...}}, but sidewaystable is a much simpler solution.